# ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground extremely slow

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login, parse-android-sdk

I am trying to log my user in with a simple Login with Facebook button with Parse Android SDK 1.9.1 using `ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground` but it takes about more than 10 seconds for the callback to fire. I have many other requests too, including downloading/uploading files, Graph requests etc after the callback returns, all of which take much less than that single login call, so it's not a connection issue. I've tried it multiple times.

Why can this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was related to something else, and in fact it wasn't caused by the API call.